# how to fix 'sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": ' error in python sqlite?

Tags: python, sqlite

i'm using sqlite to organize data fetched with a scraper script, having trouble executing an 'insert into' command.

I'm making a scraper for an electronics website as a newbie Python enthusiast.
I already had a working script that would scrape all the pages up until when i decided to modify the code to create a new column with prices and name that column using today's date.
Now for some reason the SQL command that inserts the data to the table refuses to execute with the new column i add.

Tried adding the new column to the SQL command with ? method and .format() method with no success.
Tried all kinds for ' locations around the ?s and the {}s.

This is the Code:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, prodId, title, price=None):
        self.prodId = prodId
        self.title = title
        self.price = price
        self.currDatePriceCloumnName = date + 'Price'

    def insertToTable(self):
        self.addColumn()
        conn = sqlite3.connect(databaseName)
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("insert into {} (?,?,?) values (?,?,?)".format(table),('Product_ID','Title',str(self.currDatePriceCloumnName),str(self.prodId),str(self.title),str(self.price)))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    def addColumn(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect(databaseName)
        c = conn.cursor()
        try:
            c.execute("alter table {} add column '?'".format(table),(str(self.currDatePriceCloumnName),))
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        except:
            pass
```

i expected the `c.execute` in the `insertToTable` to insert the data to the table, but what i get is this error:

```
  File "/home/sergio/Desktop/test/scraper.py", line 67, in insertToTable
    c.execute("insert into {} (?,?,?) values (?,?,?)".format(table),('Product_ID','Title',str(self.currDatePriceCloumnName),str(self.prodId),str(self.title),str(self.price)))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

The weird thing is that the the column is created but not filled.
When i used the `.format()` method, the error had the desired column name instead of the ?, this tells me that the issue might be with the fact im using `self.currDatePriceCloumnName` but i'm stuck from here.

Please help..
Thanks in advance! =]

Comment: Table and column names have to be directly in a statement; you can't use parameters for them, only for values in an expression.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Then how does it create the column in the database when addColumn is called? maybe i should've specified that the column is created but not filled.

Comment: It actually creates a new column with the desired name and not `?`? `'?'` is a string with a literal question mark, not a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in:

`c.execute("insert into {} (?,?,?) values (?,?,?)".format(table),('Product_ID','Title',str(self.currDatePriceCloumnName),str(self.prodId),str(self.title),str(self.price)))`

At:

`values (?,?,?)".format(table),`

The end of .format(table) is all you have inserted into the string. The extra `)` is causing the .format() to end throwing a syntax error because it's not expecting a `,`. You're not passing any other values.

That being said don't use string formatting with SQL statements in the future (as a general side note) as it is bad practice for security purposes:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Thanks for the response! but it raises a few questions for me, frankly i do not understand where the typo is, what i think you're saying is that a combination of format and ? won't work.. but `self.addColumn()` that runs before the problematic line actually creates the column. how is `addColumn` different than `insertToTable`? i'm using the same method in both functions while one works and the other doesn't..

Comment: `c.execute("insert into {} (?,?,?) values (?,?,?)".format(table),` Will produce the query `insert into tablename (?,?,?) values (?,?,?)`. It does not error out in the `addColumn` because `c.execute("alter table {} add column '?'".format(table),` equates to `alter table tablename add column '?'`. It is literally trying to add a column named '?'. The `insertToTable` query string is looking for 4 values, not one. When you put a closing `)` for `.format()` nothing else past that `)` will be inserted into the string.